# Problem refreshing ion-select-options when data is updated

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing an Ionic application (v.4 final release)...

My problem:
I have an `<ion-select>` and this select has a list of `<ion-select-option>`, and this options was created doing *ngFor... the problem is: when I change the array, remove an element, for example, the ionc-select-options cannot re-render the new status of this array.

```
<ion-select>
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let question of questions">{{ question }}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

(I am updating questions array)
Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
If a put the *ngFor in other element, like a div, it works fine:

example:
(It is no updating when I delete the first element)

```
<ion-select>
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let question of questions">{{ question }}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
<button (click)="deleteFirst()>Delete first!</button>
```

(It is updating when I delete the first element)

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions"></div>
<button (click)="deleteFirst()>Delete first!</button>

class MyComponent() {

      public questions = ['question1','question2','question3'];


      deleteFirst() {
        this.questions.splice(0, 1);
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you please add the code that updates the questions array?

Comment: Somethin like that:

`class MyComponent {
    public questions: Array<string> = [
        'Question 1?',
        'Question 2?',
        'Question 3?'
    ];

    deleteFirst() {
        this.questions.splice(0, 1); 
    }
}`

Comment: Ok, can you update your question where you can format your code please? I see what your problem is and will post an answer. In the meanwhile, if you can update your question with the code formatted there it would great

Comment: question updated!

Answer (score 0):

You are using [splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) alters the content of an array but doesn't change its reference.

In other words, you should work with immutable objects/Array, and create new instances when you need to make a change.

In your case :

```
deleteFirst() {
  if (this.questions.length) {
     this.questions = this.questions.filter((el, index) => index > 0);
  }
}
```

Here filter returns a new reference to an array containing objs that fulfill a condition

Comment: Well, it is not exactly my case, it is a little complex, but it is a simple way to explain you... But, follow your comment, I made this: (See the updated question)